# How to create an exact match of an image using PIL in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I'm seeing a tiny difference in image I created using PIL of python than the actual one and because of this difference my sikuli script fails to click since its an image based automation tool.

The approach is to create an image & click it, based on the object name to be clicked on screen during run-time.

Code to create image :

```
import PIL
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageEnhance

font = ImageFont.truetype("C:\\SikuliWS\\R419\\Fonts\\calibri.ttf",11)
img=Image.new("RGBA", (0,0)) #To create an empty white background
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img) #draw an image with 0,0
textsze = draw.textsize(imageString) #Create a text to capture w/h
print textsze
img=Image.new("RGBA", (textsze[0],textsze[1]+3),(255,255,255)) #create a white background as per the w/h of text passed
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
draw.text((0, 0),imageString,(13,13,13),font=font)
img.save("imageString.png", format='PNG',quality=100)
```

Output:

Actual image created:

[image: Actual image created using above code to click]

Expected image:

[image: Expected image to click]

Notice the tiny difference between characters ID and the space between characters because of which sikuli fails to click.

How do I create an exact match of image using python 2.7? Please help.

Comment: Why not turn down the sensitivity in sikuli while looking for a match? I don't think you're going to get an exact match because Windows and PIL are using different methods to render a font to an image.

Comment: The E is slightly wider in the Expected output. Are you sure these 2 images use the same font?  Also maybe antialiasing might cause it to move up a line?

Comment: The ExpectedImage doesn't look like Calibri on my machine - more like Arial Narrow

Comment: @blakev yes, i can decrease the sensitivity but as per Sikuli standards we should not do it less than 70% which may end up clicking some wrong image.

Comment: @Back2Basics Yes! as per my dev team the application under test is having same font style and size as of Microsoft Word/excel which means calibri. I tried creating image with calibri and segoeui with font size being 10/11 but both didn't work. Python generates a small image for calibri with gaps and with segoeui some what ok but doesnot work for all. If I use segoeui and try to click on other object 'Workspaces' it works but not on all. Antialising didn't help. Thanks for reply.

Comment: @SiHa yes, it is of calibri and that is how it is being generated from my python. Is there a way to create an exact replica of the expected image which will solve my problem. Please also refer my above comments on difference in image creation with fonts for more info. Thanks for reply.